# Calculate Data Fields in SQL server And update Accordingly related fields based on existing data

Tags: c#, sql-server, arrays, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I am working on EF5 in VS2012 in C#. I have two tables NIC and Network switch, with 1:M relationship. A Networkswitch can have many NICs and a NIC can be assigned to only one NetworkSwitch. Now i want is that, when we add a value to network switch i want to update the available ports and used ports based on every time we insert a new value or row in NIC table. See the code below.

```
public class NIC
{
    [Required]
    public int idNic { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [Required]
     [DisplayName("IP Address")]
    public int IPAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("idServer")]
    public int idServer { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("idNetworkSwitch")]
    public int? idNetworkSwitch { get; set; }

    [Range(1,48,ErrorMessage="The Value must be between 1 and 48")]
    [DisplayName("Network Switch Port")]
    public int? NetworkSwitchPort { get; set; }




    //Relationships
    public virtual NetworkSwitch networkSwitch { get; set; }
    public virtual Server server { get; set; }

}
 public class NetworkSwitch
{
    [Key]
    public int idNetworkSwitch { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [DisplayName("Network Switch Name")]
    public string SwitchName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(4,1024)]
    [DisplayName("Total Ports on Swich")]
    public int TotalPorts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Used Ports on Swich")]
    public int UsedPorts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Available Ports on Swich")]
    public int AvailablePorts { get; set; }

    //relationships
    public virtual Rack rack { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NIC> NICs { get; set; }




}
```

The property "UsedPorts" will have a default value of 48. So How can i calculate the properties "UsedPorts" and "AvailablePorts" ?
Also every time we insert a new ROW in NIC table we have to enter "switchport" Number. which means that it is the port on which the NIC is connected to the networkswitch. IS there a way that the user would get only those ports in this property, that are available? and when the user chooses a value that value is deleted from available ports and used ports field is update. So we can track how many ports we have on the NetworkSwitch and which Ports we have?

Comment: You're not telling enough. How do you calculate ports _at all_? When is a port available? How would you make those ports selectable? How do you "delete" an available port? From where do you get available ports in the first place?

Comment: I just added this ports Property randomly. Its not coming from somewhere. The point which i want to achive is as follows.
I want to keep data about the network switches that i have in the datacenter. Now these switches must have Ports and then a NIC can connect to this port. So lets say if i have a 48 port switch, all i want to do is to keep data in a database where i can keep a record about what ports are used by which NIC? So at any point of time i can tell how many empty ports i have that can be used. SHall i make a separate table for Ports?

Comment: A separate table was what I was thinking of too. Ports owned by a switch with a field "available".

Comment: Do you know a way that i wont put ports in a separate table and calculate the ports in program logic. for example make an array of 48ports and every time a port is used from that array update the networkswitch table properties "usedPorts" and "AvailablePorts" ?